# How can I detect upper body from shoulder to navel point?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on virtual dressing room. I am using opencv 3.0.0. I have used haarcascade to detect upper body. I do not want to show head portion in rectangle area. In rectangle area, I want to show shoulder to navel point of human body. But I cannot to do that. So I need to diminish the rectangle size to get my desire output.

This is my upperBody detection code. It detects full upper body including head.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
vid=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
_ instant=vid.read()
avg=np.float32(instant)
file=cv2.CascadeClassifier("./cascade/haarcascade_upperbody.xml")
obj=0
while(1):
 _,frame=vid.read()
 cv2.accumulateWeighted(frame, avg, 0.1)
 background=cv2.convertScaleAbs(avg)
    diff=cv2.absdiff(frame, background)
    cv2.imshow("input", frame)
    bodies=file.detectMultiScale(frame)
    for body in bodies:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (body[0], body[1]), (body[0]+body[2], body[0]+body[3]), (255,0,0), 3)
    cv2.imshow("Upper Body", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(5)==27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What does this code not do that you want it to do? Do you just need to implement "neck" and "upper legs"? What problem are you running into?

Comment: @MizanurRahman did you get the solution?